# trouble getting a filtering search bar to work

Tags: javascript, search-box

i'm trying to get a filtering search bar to work that filters results of a list as you type it in the bar, and its not working. i tried to add an event listener but that didn't seem to work well either. any ideas?

js

```
function myFunction() {
    // search for robots
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('searchbox1');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("robotlist");
    li = ul.getElementsByClassName('robotlist1');

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByClassName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

html of list i'm trying to search through:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Mr. Robot's Top Robot Models</legend>

<ul id="robotlist">
<li class="robotlist1">
  <article id="robo1">
  <h4>
  <label for="imgrobo1">  Name:</label>
     R.E.T.</h4>
  <img id="imgrobo1" src="images/roboDog.png" width=200 height=200 alt="robo1">

  <h5><strong>Description:</strong> <br>This was our first robot.
   He was modeled after the famous movie character E.T.</h5>
</article>
</li>

<li class="robotlist1">
  <article id="robo2">
<h4>
<label for="imgrobo2">  Name:</label>
   Butler.Bot</h4>
<img id="imgrobo2" src="images/robot2.png" width=200 height=200 alt="robo1">

<h5><strong>Description:</strong> <br>This was our second robot.
 He makes a mean martini!</h5>
</article>
</li>
<li class="robotlist1">
  <article id="robo3">
  <h4>
  <label for="imgrobo3">  Name:</label>
     Mega Man</h4>
  <img id="imgrobo3" src="images/robot3.png" width=200 height=200 alt="robo1">

  <h5><strong>Description:</strong> <br>This is our newest model.
   This one will follow you around the house.</h5>

</article>

</li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I can't see any element having class `a` inside li. `a = li[i].getElementsByClassName("a")[0]` will be undefined. Could you post how you bind this handler as well so that your question contains MCVE to reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp << I was attempting to follow this example, I was a bit confused about a also, I thought because it was declared at the top, that it was defining it in that line but maybe thats where the problem actually is?

also what is MCVE?

Comment: ohhhh I feel dumb, ok, yeah that IS the problem but I am trying to figure out what would go there instead. in the code example I was basing things off of, it was getelementsbytagname a... for a href links. my code doesnt have a href links, so i switched to class. i'm trying to figure out then how I would get this piece to fit with my code. I tried changing it where it got elementbyclassname and then isntead of "a" i put the class that represents each li but it didn't work when I did that either. but i'm now sure thats the issue here haha

Comment: now the question is what can I do to substitute that line that does what its supposed to do?